# Manchester UK User Group 11 March 2020

Tags: discussion, community-event

Date/Time (local): March 11, 2020, 18:00

Date/Time (UTC): March 11, 2020, 18:00

Location: Basil Chambers, 65 High Street, M4 1FS, Manchester, UK

RSVP: https://scug.co.uk/events/2020/03/manchester-sitecore-usergroup/

Manchester Sitecore User Group

The Manchester Sitecore User Group is back for the first meetup of 2020 ahead of SUGCON. Hear from Sitecore Experts sharing their knowledge and experience & network with the Sitecore Community over a few drinks and some pizza. This Sitecore User Group is kindly hosted by Valtech in their offices in Manchester. We have many great speakers joining us, and will be digging into testing personalization and optimization, using Docker with Sitecore and have a look at the new Horizon editor. If you're planning to attend, please [RSVP here](https://scug.co.uk/events/2020/03/manchester-sitecore-usergroup/).

Agenda
18:00 – 18:30 Food, Drinks and Social Time 19:00 – 20:30 Sessions 20:30 – Closing comments, end of event

Presentations
Dominic Hurst: Prioritising tests 101 
Jeremy Davis: Big site, little site, put it in a box 
Adam Seabridge: On the Horizon